# Adding meta description to the homepage (document root?)

Tags: css, html, host, meta

I made an HTML5 website, and the meta description shows up on google for all of my pages, just fine. See image 1.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXfgm.png)

However, my "home page", www.website.com, shows no meta description. See image 2. Where would I even write the meta description for it? All of my files are in the document root of my public html server.

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU9cI.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the little green arrow on the right side of URL in Google search results, it will show you when it was cached. For image2 it says Apr 1, 2016 03:21:17 GMT (for image1 it is Apr 14, 2016 18:56:32 GMT). If meta tag was not there in that time you just need to wait for google bots to recache your web.

Answer (score 0):

description meta tags are directory wide, so your pages need to be in separate directories. It is also a good idea as it keeps a clean URL structure (no menu.html, just menu/). To do this, just create a menu folder with your menu.html inside this folder as index.html. Then add the meta tags to these pages. That should work.

Directory structure:

```
root
|
 \
  -index.html
  |
  -menu
  |   \
  |    -index.html
  |
  -contact
         \
          -index.html
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using this type of folder structure now, as opposed to dropping everything in the root. This is much, much better.

Comment: Thus, the home page/root www.example.com will take the meta from whatever is in index.html. But, if I had index.html, services.html, contact.html etc. in the root, it wouldn't know which meta to take from? That's my main question here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your home page showed up directory listing when google crawler came to visit it, Hence google is showing the contents of the directory(cgi-bin, ftpquota...) as description in search results.

Try submitting URL to google manually at the below URL, and it will sort out the issue, but it will take some time.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue&pli=1

**Edit**

Yes, my guess was correct, this is what your site looked like on 1st April when crawler visited the site.

[Cached page](http://106.10.137.112/search/srpcache?p=http%3A%2F%2Fheidisinhomepetcare.com%2F&fr=yfp-t-101&ei=UTF-8&u=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:n4sRdRb-nNIJ:http://www.heidisinhomepetcare.com/%20http%3A%2F%2Fheidisinhomepetcare.com%2F&icp=1&.intl=in&sig=FFdeckA6_AIqAgfhijwscA--)

> No worries when next time crawlers index the page they'll update their index with the current description. But the problem is we can't guess when it will happen. even if you submit url manually also search engines will take some time to update their indexes with latest.

Answer (score -1):

Add a description meta tag

```
<meta content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit" name="description">
```

Comment: That's what he's done, but it's showing up for all pages